# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: laravel

**Error:**

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mmictltd.admins' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `admins` where `email` = kayondoronald2015@gmail.com limit 1)

My **create_admin_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admin');
    }
}
```

[Laravel error illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpjQ.png)

Comment: I wonder why it says  select * from `admins` yet my table is admin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your table's in migration is called 'admin' but in query you are looking for 'admins'.

You can specific table name in your model by $table:

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'admin';
```

Laravel convention is that table names should be plural in this case: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

So I recommend you to change your migration from 'admin' to 'admins'.

Comment: @OP Although, I'd recommend sticking to Laravel's conventions and reading the docs to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

By default laravel uses the **"snake case"**, plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So inside your **Admin** eloquent model you must define the **$table** property for your case as

```
protected $table = 'admin';
```

Check the eloquent model class convetion here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar difficulty trying to deploy my application on App engine. I will share with you how I fixed it.

- remove routes from api.php (I didn't need these for my application)
- enable cloud SQL api [enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin&redirect=https:%2F%2Fconsole.cloud.google.com&_ga=2.164522367.-1360075521.1510572080)
- Follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible)  **follow next two steps before deploying**
- make the following changes to the composer.json file. The tutorial is incorrect.
  ```
  "post-install-cmd": [
              "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
              "php artisan optimize",
              "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
          ]
  ```
- Configure your app.yaml file like so:
  ```
  runtime: php
  env: flex

  runtime_config:
    document_root: public

  env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_LOG: errorlog
    APP_KEY: APP_KEY (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    CACHE_DRIVER: database
    SESSION_DRIVER: database
    ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
    DB_HOST: localhost
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_DATABASE: DATABASE_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_USERNAME: USERNAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD (DO NOT USE QUOTES)
    DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME (DO NOT USE QUOTES)

    QUEUE_DRIVER: database

  beta_settings:
      # for Cloud SQL, set this value to the Cloud SQL connection name,
      # e.g. "project:region:cloudsql-instance"
      cloud_sql_instances: "YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
  ```