# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'restaurent.sessions' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

How I can fix this error in Laravel?

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'restaurent.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions`
> where `id` = Qivf2Trpe45sYfbLci9TzcfKNsIKBZOWH2vKTbbv limit 1)

Comment: The referenced table does not exist in your database, so; 1) do you have a migration for that table, 2) have you performed a migration (`php artisan migrate`)?

Comment: Sometimes, it gets all values of .env files from its generated cache. On that scenario, simply run the following command to remove the cache for .env.
``php artisan config:clear``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966767/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table)

Comment: @Sonu can you please share your model as well as the migration file and add code if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. Database config is true in `.env`.
2. Run `php artisan migrate` to create table.